# API with hundrets of forms - out of memory

Tags: php, forms, symfony, out-of-memory

In my Symfony 2.6 project I have API for mobile app that gives a possibility to add and object with lots of data.

Main form consists of collection of other forms. Each of child forms have the same things, 4 in total. So the structure looks like this:

Master form has **Child1** forsm which has **Child2** forms which has **Child3** forms.

The object has for instance 2 000 entities for **Child3**, 8 **Child2** entities, 3 **Child1** entities and one Master entity.

Many times I get this error while saving data:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 88 bytes) in /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.php on line 755\n'

I have just add types to all forms elements, like:

```
$buider->add('startLangutude', 'text')
```

Also I have turned off SQLLogger. Is there any other neat solution that could help here? Do you have any experience in it and could share?

Comment: Perhaps you could reduce the number of forms?  2000 forms, especially on a mobile app, seems a bit excessive.

Comment: Mobile app is sending a JSON structure to my web API. This API is based on Symfony forms. When request with JSON gets to a server, SYmfony creates those forms based on it, validates and saves to DB.
This 2000 entities is just 3 elements: latitude, longitude and date.

Comment: maybe use some request accelerator that caches your form responses like varnish. so it wont be executed everytime

Comment: Ok. 2 thousand records still seems a lot.  You can of course bump up your memory limit.  Otherwise, don't use S2 forms for processing that much data.

Comment: Personally, it sounds like you should re-evaluate your design. Loading 2000 entities is not something you should ever do. Consider from a user experience, what information do they actually need. What information can you defer loading? What are your breakpoints? Using these questions, design a new workflow that allows you to be minimalistic instead of eager.

Comment: I need to upload from mobile app GPS location points for 20km long route. This is about 2000 points. I need those points to show it then on map. How could work flow look here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest You to drop `Form` approach and use simple `json_decode` to get array (it's cheaper resource wise compared to Object), then create a bunch of `ArrayToEntityTransformer` using `StrategyPattern`. In each strategy You can validate given array before object creation process. If object is valid, use [doctrine batch processing](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) recommendations to save memory by clearing `EntityManager` after each batch.

Good luck.

Comment: I will definitely switch from Forms (which by the way are huge objects as I try to debug it) to clear json and json_decode. This is the best idea, thanks. I will also use batch processing but I have one problem with it. Maybe you could look at it in this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304323/doctrine-entitymanager-clear-method-in-nested-entities)