# Doctrine EntityManager clear method in nested entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, batch-processing

I would like to use [doctrine batch insert processing](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) in order to optimize insert of a big amount of entities. The problem is with Clear method. It says that this method detach all entities that are managed by EntityManager. So what should I do in a situation where I have a parent Entity, which has many child, and each child has their childs, like this:

- riseSession

  - track

    - points

So I have 1 rideSession, 3 tracks and each track has for isntance 2 000 points. I could use batch processing in last loop which is responsible for saving points. But if I use clear method, then how to set parents for points and tracks? Clear method will detach them, right?

Comment: What is your problem? What do you have? What do you want to achieve? If you now have all your objects in memory why do you want to use this method of batch processing? It is for optimal managing memory: when all your objects cannot be stored in memory at time. And so you need to create objects and then detach all entities (release memory) in a loop. It optimises memory in PHP script.

Comment: So if I have 40000 objects in Memory (entities decoded from JSON), then I can be sure that when I invoke $em->flush() server won't crash with  OOM exception? Cause this is what I understood from your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soon You will hit memory limit. The idea of `flush()` in batches is ok, but You need to `clear()` `EntityManager` at the end of each batch to release used memory.

But in Your case, You will have `ORMInvalidArgumentException` (a.k.a. "new entity foung through relationship") if You will call `$child->setParent($parent);` after You did `$entityManager->clear();`.

Problem is that `$parent` is now in `detached` state in `UnitOfWork`. So You need to put it again in `managed` state. This can be done by using `$entityManager->merge();` or simply by using `$parentRepository->find($parent->getId());`.

Just make sure to bring up all Entities to `managed` state after each `clear()` in case You going to use them later.

Comment: This was exactly the thing I was referring to. This was exactly my problem. Thank you @Valentas !!

Answer (score 2):

If you have all your 40000 objects already loaded in memory then you can just use code without clearing. Clearing on entity manager are used for optimising memory in PHP script. If you have enough memory to store all the objects you don't need to clear entity manager at all.

To optimise memory in that case you can `unset($entity)` after every persist.

And to fit DB connection bandwidth you can group several entities as in example.

```
$batchSize = 20;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {
    $em->persist($entities[$i]);
    unset($entities[$i]);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush();
    }
}
$em->flush(); //Persist objects that did not make up an entire batch
```

Comment: I guess here we have 3 memory use cases: array returned by json_decode(), entities objects created in the loop while parsing previously mentioned array and EntityManager with persisted entities. So the best way would be probably using clear while making flush, as @Valentas wrote, and use unset to array elements pulled from json_decode and maybe null entities after they are persisted? I marked Valentas response as the acceptance of the answer because my question was referring to this particular problem but thank you for your help too.